# GParted: Extending to unallocated space in the left

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I want to resize the boot partition to the unallocated space. I know that I have to run GParted in live USB mode. I can delete the fat32 partition. How can I increase the size of the boot partition without losing data? What's the right way?

GParted:

[image]

Results of `sudo parted -l` :

[image]

Comment: If new UEFI system the FAT32 partition has all your UEFI boot files. It is not a boot partition, but the ESP - efi system partition. And most Ubuntu installs do not need a /boot partition nor swap, just ESP & / (root)? Post this: `sudo parted -l` so we can see partitions here.

Comment: @oldfred **Every** system should have a swap partition or file. Esp if you plan on hibernating your system.

Comment: Status update please. See my answer, below. Please remember to accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/sda6 left (*or delete it if you wish*)
- **move** /dev/sda7 left
- **resize** /dev/sda7 to the right
- click the Apply button

Comment: Best to resize NTFS partitions with Windows tools and reboot into Windows immediately as it has to run chkdsk after any resize. And make sure Windows fast start up which sets hibernation flag is off, or gparted will not see NTFS partitions and may cause issues.

Comment: @oldfred I agree that Windows should be used to manipulate NTFS partitions. However we're working with a FAT32 (probably used for sharing files with Windows), and OP has already indicated that they could just delete it. And, of course, an ext4 partition for /. I assumed that by "boot partition" OP meant Ubuntu root. So I think that we're good to go as per my answer.